# How to use Neo4j with graphQL from java context

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, cypher, graphql

To be honest I am very confused by the GraphQL + Java + Neo4J combination.

The question may be a bit chaotic but this is caused by my utter confusion :)

I would like to use GraphQL in combination with Neo4j and I am Java backend developer so I would prefer to use also Java somewhere in the stack.

- Neo4j is coming with a pluging that directly translates GraphQL queries to Cypher and returns result.
- At the same time Neo4j has this react module https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql-js that is again doing more or less the same. Translates GraphQL to cypher.

There are couple of things I don't understand:

1. Is the plugin that comes with NEO4j something man would use in production, or some sort of complementary search mechanism. So in a way the front would connect to your Java endpoint for the more complex functionality and to your Neo4j directly for your Query functionality.
2. How do I build a good Java stack ? If I use GraphQL to Cypher ytranslation mechanism - for example this one: https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql-java . Do I still need to write Resolvers ? Can I write resolvers only for some of the queries while using the translating library for others. How do I configure the two mechanisms to co-exist?
3. Can I use Spring Boot on top of such stack, and if I can use Spring boot than can I use customer Resolvers for some queries and the GraphQL to Cypher translators for other queries.

Thanks

Comment: Hello @Alexandar Petrov could you help me with integrating Neo4j GraphQL Java within spring boot?